# PHP: How to use facebook status.set method using php?

Tags: php, facebook

I need to update facebook status using the status.set method of the facebook API. I have already created an application and am able to login using the Facebook API's sample code. I have downloaded the Facebook PHP SDK 2.1.2 from Facebook. I also use the facebook.php and fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt file in my working directory. But the problem is when I go to update my status using below code, then a long error shows.

> SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed error code:60

My code is below:

```
require './facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
'appId'  => '...',  
'secret' => '...',  
'cookie' => true, // enable optional
 cookie support ));

try{
    $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'status.set',
        'status' => $_POST['hello'],
        'uid' => '...'
    ));
} 
catch(Exception $o){ print_r($o);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem.pls see the link:

> [How get facebook user ID from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780416/how-get-facebook-user-id-from-my-application/5788478#5788478)

Hope it can help u all